# Different plans on Readonly Secondary Replica

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, optimization, cardinality-estimates, query-performance

We have an AlwaysOn environment where we use the async readonly secondary replica for reporting purpose.

One of the reports intermittently runs for much longer than normal.  I can see when it runs slowly the plan is taking a different route and causing a clustered index scan on a big table.

However, when I run the same query in primary replica it runs fine and generates a plan that is what we expect.

Why does it generate a good plan on the primary replica but a bad plan on the secondary? what are the possible reasons?

The servers have exactly the same hardware and the configuration is the same.

Comment: Are there any temporary stats on the secondary that it may be using? `use MyDB; go; SELECT * FROM sys.stats where is_temporary = 1;`

Comment: Yeah, thats the bit i am confused about.
When I do
SELECT * FROM sys.stats where is_temporary = 1 and object_id=object_id('tablename')
I find a few but non that ends with suffix _readonly_database_statistic.
So what does that mean.  How are they temporary without having the suffix _readonly_database_statistic

Comment: This sounds like a possible bug around temporary statistics on readonly secondaries.  Perhaps file a bug report on http://connect.microsoft.com - also, see https://duckduckgo.com/?q=readonly+secondaries+temporary+statistics+%22_readonly_database_statistic%22++site%3Aconnect.microsoft.com&t=ffsb&atb=v46-3&ia=web for several possibly related issues.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in SQL Server, if you are using SQL Server 2012, 2014, or 2016 install the latest SP with CU that has a fix to This.

Details here:

[FIX: Bad query plan created on secondary replicas after statistics updated via FULLSCAN option on primary replica in SQL Server 2012 or 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013236/fix-bad-query-plan-created-on-secondary-replicas-after-statistics-upda)